# Pandas: shiftafter N strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
        atm_id     dNDCSessionTime  sCardNumber  nTrRequestCount  
152865       0 2017-01-14 07:56:17            1                1   
153052       0 2017-01-14 08:01:13            1                1   
153053       0 2017-01-14 08:02:19            1                1   
153054       0 2017-01-14 08:03:41            1                1   
152804       0 2017-01-14 08:04:37            1                1   
152805       0 2017-01-14 08:05:24            1                1   
152806       1 2017-01-14 08:06:08            1                1   
152807       1 2017-01-14 08:07:15            1                1   
152808       1 2017-01-14 08:08:08            1                1   
152866       1 2017-01-14 08:08:50            1                1
```

I need add new columns, that, means period. (For every atm_id every 3 transaction (strings in dataframe))

Desire output

```
            atm_id     dNDCSessionTime  sCardNumber  nTrRequestCount period
152865       0 2017-01-14 07:56:17            1                1      1
153052       0 2017-01-14 08:01:13            1                1      1
153053       0 2017-01-14 08:02:19            1                1      1
153054       0 2017-01-14 08:03:41            1                1      2
152804       0 2017-01-14 08:04:37            1                1      2
152805       0 2017-01-14 08:05:24            1                1      2
152806       1 2017-01-14 08:06:08            1                1      3
152807       1 2017-01-14 08:07:15            1                1      3
152808       1 2017-01-14 08:08:08            1                1      3
152866       1 2017-01-14 08:08:50            1                1      4
```

I try to do this with

```
df['period'] = df.sort_values(['atm_id', 'dNDCSessionTime']).groupby('atm_id').shift(500)
```

But I've got an error.

Comment: Your desired result is unclear. Why do you want 3x`1`, **2x`2`**, 3x`3`, 2x`4`?

Comment: @NilsWerner thank you, you're right. It was my mistake. I've fix that

Answer (score 0):

If like in your example, the number of rows per 'atm_id' is a multiple of 3, then you can use `iloc[::3]` to select every 3 rows.

```
# initiate the column
df['Period'] = None
# select every three rows and assign 1 there in the column Period
df['Period'].iloc[::3] = 1
# use cumsum, ffill and astype to populate an incremental value every 3 rows
df['Period'] = df['Period'].cumsum().ffill().astype(int)
```

Now, I assume that you won't have always a number of rows multiple of 3 within an `atm_id`, so you can go by `groupby` and `apply`. I added a row to your input with `atm_id = 2` to make the point. If you do:

```
print (df.groupby('atm_id').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::3]))

               atm_id     dNDCSessionTime  sCardNumber  nTrRequestCount Period
atm_id                                                                        
0      152865       0 2017-01-14 07:56:17            1                1   None
       153054       0 2017-01-14 08:03:41            1                1   None
1      152806       1 2017-01-14 08:06:08            1                1   None
       152866       1 2017-01-14 08:08:50            1                1   None
2      152887       2 2017-01-12 07:56:17            1                1   None
```

so you get every 3 rows within a same `atm_id`. Here different solutions are possible to use the above information in `df`, mine is to go by index numbers, assuming there are unique in your data. Create a `mask` with original index number and use it with the same idea than above.

```
mask_index = df.groupby('atm_id').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[::3]).index.get_level_values(1)
#if you do print (mask_index), you get
#Out[35]: Int64Index([152865, 153054, 152806, 152866, 152887], dtype='int64')

# initiate the column
df['Period'] = None
# select every three rows within a same atm_id and assign 1 there in the column Period
df.loc[mask_index, 'Period'] = 1
# use cumsum, ffill and astype to populate have an incremental value every 3 rows
df['Period'] = df['Period'].cumsum().ffill().astype(int)
```

the result is like

```
        atm_id     dNDCSessionTime  sCardNumber  nTrRequestCount  Period
152865       0 2017-01-14 07:56:17            1                1       1
153052       0 2017-01-14 08:01:13            1                1       1
153053       0 2017-01-14 08:02:19            1                1       1
153054       0 2017-01-14 08:03:41            1                1       2
152804       0 2017-01-14 08:04:37            1                1       2
152805       0 2017-01-14 08:05:24            1                1       2
152806       1 2017-01-14 08:06:08            1                1       3
152807       1 2017-01-14 08:07:15            1                1       3
152808       1 2017-01-14 08:08:08            1                1       3
152866       1 2017-01-14 08:08:50            1                1       4
152887       2 2017-01-12 07:56:17            1                1       5
```

where you can see the increment from 4 to 5 between the last two rows while there is not 3 rows for `Period=4` as you change `atm_id`

Note: if your indexes are not unique, a `reset_index` at the beginning and `set_index` back at the end gives the same result, also I did not `sort_values` as you, but it's not a problem.